# Using CMPLX function for double or quad precision in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is my code:

```
    Program Complex_Double_Quad_Precision

    Use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env

    Implicit none

    Integer, parameter :: sp = REAL32
    Integer, parameter :: dp = REAL64
    Integer, parameter :: qp = REAL128

    Real(sp),parameter:: Some_Value_0 = 4.56
    Real(dp),parameter:: Some_Value_1 = 4.56
    Real(qp),parameter:: Some_Value_2 = 4.56

    Complex(sp):: Value_0
    Complex(dp):: Value_1
    Complex(qp):: Value_2

    Value_0 = cmplx( Some_Value_0 , Some_Value_0 )
    Value_1 = cmplx( Some_Value_1 , Some_Value_1 )
    Value_2 = cmplx( Some_Value_2 , Some_Value_2 )

    Write(*,*) Value_0
    Write(*,*) Value_1
    Write(*,*) Value_2

    End Program Complex_Double_Quad_Precision
```

My IDE:
CodeBlocks 16.01.

I have intention to learn how to use double or quad precision in complex calculations. In my code, after compiling and starting a code I got this message:

> Conversion from REAL(8) to default-kind COMPLEX(4)  might lose precision, consider using the KIND argument

Is there any way to change the precision for the `CMPLX` function result using the `KIND` argument and `dp` and `qp`?

Comment: Just like i said, i got that message afther compiling so, that means: 
1. CMPLX function make conversion from `dp` to `sp` for `Value_1`
2. CMPLX function make conversion from `qp` to `sp` for `Value_2`
How can i force a CMPLX function to get a result which is, in first case `dp` and in second case `qp`?

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread your question ("with using" as "with_out_ using").  I've edited your question so others don't make the same silly mistake.  If you think I've actually changed what you mean, just roll it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the warning message says, you want to use the optional third argument to CMPLX specifying the kind of the returned value. See e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CMPLX.html

Or, in your code:

```
Value_1 = cmplx( Some_Value_1 , Some_Value_1, dp )
Value_2 = cmplx( Some_Value_2 , Some_Value_2, qp )
```